# PostgreSQL: use same connection or get another from pool?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres, pg-promise

I have a `Node.js` script and a `PostgreSQL` database, and I'll be using a library that maintains a pool of connections to the database.

Say I have a script that queries the database multiple times (**not** a *transaction*) at different parts of the script, how do I tell if I should acquire a single connection/client and reuse it throughout*, or acquire a new client from the pool for each query? (Both works but which has better performance?)

*`task` in the `pg-promise` library, `connect` in the `node-postgres` library.

---

```
...
// Acquire connection from pool.
(Database query)
(Non-database-related code)
(Database query)
// Release connection to pool.
...
```

or

```
...
// Acquire connection from pool.
(Database query)
// Release connection to pool.
(Non-database-related code)
// Acquire connection from pool.
(Database query)
// Release connection to pool.
...
```

Comment: Have you read this? - [Chaining Queries](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/chaining-queries).

Comment: @vitaly-t Why does the second method "deplete the pool"? Doesn't the client get release back into it after each query?

Comment: Depletion due to high concurrency, i.e. with more queries trying to execute in parallel than the overall number of connections available in the pool. The new ones will be stuck, waiting for a connection to become available in the pool. That's why the use of tasks is important in a busy system.

Comment: @vitaly-t I don't get it. Each instance of the script would only be executing at most one query at a time regardless of which method used. No?

Comment: In an HTTP service queries are executed concurrently, as do HTTP handlers, so there can be any number of concurrent queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use node-postgres module that will make you task easier.
And about your question when to use pool here is the brief answer.

> PostgreSQL server can only handle 1 query at a time per connection.
>   That means if you have 1 global new pg.Client() connected to your
>   backend your entire app is bottleknecked based on how fast postgres
>   can respond to queries. It literally will line everything up, queuing
>   each query. Yeah, it's async and so that's alright...but wouldn't you
>   rather multiply your throughput by 10x? Use pg.connect set the 
>   pg.defaults.poolSize to something sane (we do 25-100, not sure the
>   right number yet).
>
> new pg.Client is for when you know what you're doing. When you need a
>   single long lived client for some reason or need to very carefully
>   control the life-cycle. A good example of this is when using 
>   LISTEN/NOTIFY. The listening client needs to be around and connected
>   and not shared so it can properly handle NOTIFY messages. Other
>   example would be when opening up a 1-off client to kill some hung
>   stuff or in command line scripts.

here is the link of that module.
Hopefully this will help.
https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres

You can see the documentation over there and about the pooling. Thanks :)

And about closing the pool it provides the callback done which can be called when you want to close that pool.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, how the pool you are using works, but normally they should reuse the connections (don't disconnect after use), so you do not need to be concerned with caching connections.